# Vue 3 usage of v-model changes Bootstrap 5 table class

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

Below is an example of the code I was writing:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <tr class="table-dark">
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th colspan="3">Column 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-info">
        <th></th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>0</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="category"
            value="0"
            v-model="categoryMdl"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="category"
            value="1"
            v-model="categoryMdl"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="category"
            value="2"
            v-model="categoryMdl"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Initially, before I added the v-model, the code was displaying the Bootstrap 5 table classes correctly. It was only after I added that the classes in the table were not working properly.

I have other bootstrap classes out of the table and it is working fine.

Any idea why introducing v-model into my table column interferes with the bootstrap class? And is there a way to fix it?

I'm at a loss as I have only recently started using Vue. Tried looking up solutions but the closest I got was "putting them in the child element". But my input is the child element and it's creating havoc.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should remove from the inputs the attribute value="..." and set them in data:

```
data() {
   return {
      categoryMdl1 : 0,
      categoryMdl2 : 1,
      categoryMdl3 : 2,
   }
}
```

Then update HTML

```
<td>
    <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="category"
        v-model="categoryMdl1"
/>
</td>
<td>
    <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="category"
        v-model="categoryMdl2"
/>
</td>
<td>
    <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="category"
        v-model="categoryMdl3"
/>
</td>
```

Docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#lazy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).